# Javascript error "Reduce of empty array with no initial value"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got an error like

> Reduce of empty array with no initial value

when do following:

```js
var fields = $(".invoiceli");
$(document).delegate(fields, 'change', function() {
  Array.prototype.reduce.call(fields, function(prev, curr)
    //.....
  });
})
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The reduce function expects either a non-empty array or an initial value as parameter.

Try this

```
Array.prototype.reduce.call(fields, function (prev, curr) ..... }, null);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce` expects 3 parameters, you just have 2, so no initial value is given.